# Best practices for moving css styles into Sass files

Tags: css, sass

Our current Angular 4 project currently uses pure Css, however I am recommending the use of SASS. I am going with the VSCode IDE and the Live-Sass-Compiler extension (so far working quite well), and webpack is used to bundle the current "..\src\styles.css" file.

I have moved some 800+ lines from styles.css into _base.scss (as is), and my new sass folder structure I've created is:

- src

  - sass

    _base.scss

    _variables.scss

    main.scss

Where main.scss looks like:

```
@import "_variables.scss";
@import "_base.scss";
```

My primary question is two-folder: what is the best practice for refactoring all of this styling into my new main.scss file ? And should I create new sass variables in _varialbes.scss and use them inside _base.scss ?

If my question is too broad, I will try and narrow it down.

regards.

Comment: Hi bob, best practices questions are off-topic at Stack Overflow because they are opinion-based (even if most people share the same opinion).

Comment: oh well. I had a gut feeling that might be the case. @TylerH

Comment: Luckily there are many sites that already talk about best practices for Sass, including this one https://sass-guidelin.es/

Answer (score 4):

You can use new variables on `_base.scss` if you `"@import _variables.scss";`.
And you don't need to use `_` when you importing `scss files` `_` just means partial.

you can import your scss files without `_` this.

```
@import "variables.scss";
@import "base.scss";
```

Here is the some best practices [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/8-tips-help-get-best-sass/)